# System will hang after start for a while if I disable typer-threading in BIOS

Tags: boot

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.My cpu is i9 9900k
I found that if I turn HT off in BIOS,after I strat Ubuntu and get in to desktop for a while,it will
get freeze.
I have test on windows 10,it works fine...
I just want to turn off HT to keep my cpu cool...thougt it's cold in my country

Comment: Can you post output from dmesg it would be easier to see if there is anything in the log

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by many things.

It is more likely that you activated overclock, and the Hardware can't cope with the memory timings or other tunnables.
Or maybe your computer has an air flow problem and hangs randomly.

HT brings more parallel capacity and tasks would be completed sooner. So CPU speed will be reduced sooner that without HT, and reducing the speed reduces the heat generated.

Sounds possible that a memory module is not working well, and it generates a hang on the system when it gets heat. That would be independent of if you have HT activated or not. Would be random hangs.

Or for example, it could be that your laptop is configured to hibernate if there is no activity for a while, and you don't have enough swap, so it crashes.

But you don't need to disable HT, you'll get no get variation in temperature.

There is a nice thread in here:
https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/ive-heard-that-turning-off-hyperthreading-can-cool-down-the-cpu-temps.2438840/

Also some laptops have bad air flow. If you replaced internal components the new ones may be blocking a bit the air flow.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,it's weird that even when I activate overclock,if HT is enable,it works fine...but it will hang after I turn off HT

Answer (score 0):

You may need to also update your `/etc/default/grub` file to explicitly state that HyperThreading should not be used on your machine. To do so, do this:

1. Open a terminal
2. Open the `/etc/default/grub` file with `sudo`:
   `sudo vi /etc/default/grub`
3. Find the line that starts `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`
4. Add `noht` (for No HyperThreading) to the end of the line before the last quote. For example, on my system, it would look like this:
   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash noht"`
5. Update Grub with:
   `sudo update-grub`
6. Reboot

If the goal is to keep the core temperatures of your CPU down, you may also want to consider instead using `cpufrequtils`. This is how I keep my systems cooler in the summer because they can *idle* at 70˚C in July.

This is how I do it:

0. Install `cpufrequtils` if it's not already on the system:
   `sudo apt install cpufrequtils`
1. Run `cpufreq-info` to see what governors and limits are in place already on the CPU
2. Call `cpufreq-set --cpu 0 --max 2.8GHz` for each CPU core on your machine, setting the GHz value to your desired limit

In my case, my primary development server has an 8-core CPU that tops out around 3.8GHz under load and can easily hit 110˚C within 30 seconds if I'm not careful. So in mid-April I will put a governor on each of the CPU cores to limit the maximum scale-up to 2.8GHz (or a little higher if I'm working on some time-critical stuff). In November I remove the governors and let the system use *all t3h Hz*. This generally keeps the CPU under 85˚C under load in the summer.

Hope one of these two options gives you what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks for your reply.but I got same result